# Vuetify Autocomplete will not Render

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js

I am developing a UI with Vue, and I'm using Vuetify's framework for its awesome components.

So far I have used v-toolbar, v-card, v-text, v-select, and a couple others and everything has worked great. However, for some reason when I try to use v-autocomplete it won't load! It'll load everything around it but not the autocomplete itself. This is the error I get in browser console:

```
Unknown custom element: <v-autocomplete> - did you register the 
component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the 
"name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

Are there any ideas on what I can try to get autocomplete to work? (I've already tried copy/pasting the VAutocomplete's folder into my app's node_modules folder but maybe I need to add it in another place?) Thanks!

Comment: Did you upgrade `vuetify` to version `1.1`? Depending on your `package.json` you could just run `npm i vuetify` in your project root. Don't alter node_modules manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kinda happening with everyone out there, Vuetify just got a new version released(like 2-3 days back), *V1.1*. The UI Component `<v-autocomplete>` was added in the very same version, i.e., it is one of the latest component Vuetify has now.

So now you need to check and make sure whether your Vuetify (the one you have installed) is updated to the version *V1.1*, which you can do just by looking into *devDependencies* or *dependencies* of the file *package.json* of your project.

File: package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.1.1", <-- something like this
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

In order to update your Vuetify to *V1.1*, all you need to do is the followinng in the terminal

```
npm i vuetify
```

This will remove any previous version of the vuetify and install a lastest version of it.

I recommend you do that(update your vuetify). As the *V1.1* has many more interesting and useful components, which you should look into.

However if for some reasons you don't want to update it then I would suggest you to use `<v-select>` with `autocomplete` prop, `<v-select>` is a component which is there in vuetify since inception. This does the exact same thing, but just few minor things are missing (that's why you should update). You can use `<v-select>` like this.

```
<v-select
            autocomplete
            append-icon="label"
            :items='getTags'
            multiple
            hint="Atleast 3 tags required"
            v-model="tagy"
            :search-input.sync="search"
            :loading = "loading"
            cache-items
            editable
            flat
            placeholder="Select only suggested tags"
            >
</v-select>
```

Well that's all, I still recommend you to update to *V1.1* and go for `<v-autocomplete>`.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: OMG thank you! That was exactly the problem I had, I just updated in my project directory and autocomplete worked!!!